# How to get the absolute path of a FileHandle in libgdx

Tags: libgdx

FileHandle seems to only provide functions to get relative paths to a actual file.
How to get the absolute path of a FileHandle?

Answer (score 1):

FileHandle provides a function called `file()` it returns a `File` object which may be used to call `getAbsolutePath()`

in short: `String absolutePath = fileHandle.file().getAbsolutePath();`